iPhone ringer is off except when I have my hearing aids in
After the last 2 iOS updates the incoming calls do not ring. The volume is set to maximum, but the ringer bell has a slash through it and will not for a call.
When I have my hearing aids in, I hear the ringtone through the hearing aids. When I have the hearing aids on the charger, I can’t hear incoming calls, alerts or notifications.
Everything appears to be turned on in settings/sounds and haptics.
How do I turn the ringer on on the iPhone? Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Welcome to Ask Different. What is your iPhone model and the iOS version installed on it?

This depends on phone and version. Do you still have an iPhone with a physical ringer switch? Use that. The switch position towards you turns the ringer on. (I seem to recall that there was an ability to disconnect the switch with this setting in the System Preferences -> Sound options, but I now use an iPhone 15 so I cannot verify. But…)
Do you have a newer iPhone (iPhone 15 or 16) with the "Action Button" above the volume controls? Holding that button acts as your Ringer Switch by default, but it might be rebound to something else (System Preferences -> Action Button). If you have an Action Button, you should have the Ringer state in your Control Center. Swipe down from the very top right of the phone, and the Bell icon will either be "off" (like the majority of other buttons there) which is the normal state, where the normal state is when it WILL ring. But based off your description the Bell icon will have a slash through it. Tap it to cycle it.
 
One last possibility is that you have Notifications for the Phone app turned off. (System Preferences -> Notifications. Scroll down to Phone, tap it and review its settings.) However, these settings being turned off do not have are not consistent with the "bell with the slash through it" visual you described.

If there is something unique that happens in cases with the Hearing Aid configurations, I'm not aware of it.
